# How to add content to Nuxt i18n in page (wordpress headless cms)

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use Wordpress as a headless CMS and pull the content in using Nuxt, which I'm using as a SSG. I have a few languages that I need to translate it to but can't quite work out how to make this work.

I would like to do something like this, but it doesn't work as the  blocks only seem to take strings:

```
<i18n>
{
  "en": en,
  "nb": nb
}
</i18n>

<template>
  <div class="container">
    {{ $t('frontpage_top_section.frontpage_heading') }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData() {
      const en = await fetch('https://wordpressurl.net/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/4685').then(res => res.json());
      const nb = await fetch('https://wordpressurl.net/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/4235').then(res => res.json());
      return {
        en, nb
      }
  },
}
</script>
```

What is the right approach here? How can I pull the content from Wordpress api on a per page/component basis and use it within the template?

Let me know if I've missed anything out and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So i've worked this out and I thought I would share here incase anyone else is confused. If anyone wants to elaborate on this feel free.

So what I did is not to try and include this in the page/component itself but to use separate files to call the data, as can be seen here: https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/lazy-load-translations

So in nuxt.config.js I have:

```
  modules: [
[
  'nuxt-i18n',
  {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en-US.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'nb',
        iso: 'nb_NO',
        name: 'Norwegian',
        file: 'nb.js'
      },
    ],
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'lang/',
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    seo: true
  },
]
]
```

And then for example, in /lang/en-US.js I call the specific pages for that language (and do the same for the other languages):

```
export default async (context, locale) => {
let homepage = await fetch('https://wordpressurl.net/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/4685').then(res => res.json());
let about = await fetch('https://wordpressurl.net/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/9519').then(res => res.json());
return {
    homepage, about
}
}
```

And then in my templates I can call:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
{{ $t('homepage.acf.frontpage_top_section.frontpage_heading') }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Now when i load the page, the correct content is shown and if I go to, for example: /nb the Norwegian content is shown.